# Can closed questions be edited by their owners?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)

When a question has been marked "Closed," is the user who asked it (the OP) allowed to edit it? Editing and rewording might make the question valid. Without editing abilities, the OP will have to ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as owner of the question you can always edit, vote to close/reopen or delete it.

Answer (score 6):

This is, IMHO, one of the best uses for closing (vs. simple deletion): it allows the author (or other editors) to expand on what little good might exist in an otherwise poor question, while reacting to criticism. When sufficiently improved, the question can then be re-opened and answered, without piles of now-offtopic answers having collected in the interim.

Comment: Wow. Good point. I used to question the purpose of "closing" as a step towards "deletion".

Comment: I wonder though how many of these questions will actually be re-opened even after clarification. Since 5? users have to vote to reopen before the answers can even start to be posted.

Answer (score 1):

Also people with enough reputation can edit any questions. Open, Closed or even Deleted questions (10k+)

Comment: @Ólafur Waage: Thanks for the clarification!