# Is it possible to edit a question without leaving revision history?

Tags: support, answers, edits, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an editing ‘grace period’ on answers after they have been posted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted)

I could've sworn an answer just changed after I refreshed the page, but I can't see any revision history... So as the title says, is this possible, or am I just going crazy?

Maybe by users over 10k? Or if you edit within a certain time frame?

Comment: Five minute window: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted

Comment: Waiting on one more vote to close...

Comment: This is sadly exciting. Who will be the fifth vote? Oh, one of *those* diamond people.