# Can the same answer from the same question be bountied multiple times by the same user (non-concurrently)?

Tags: support, bounties

There is a question I asked which had an in depth answer. I provided a bounty, but the issue was only semi resolved. Due to new discovery, it turns out the answer was correct in a partial context, and was useful in moving towards finding the answer. I would like to provide an additional bounty to the answer (the answer already has a bounty on it from me). Is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have awarded multiple bounties to the same answer on Meta. Checking....

Comment: @Pekka - Thx, I just don't want to waste 200 rep :D

Comment: This question has some multiple bounties. I'm on the ipad so I can't check whether they are all from me, but if they are, it's definitely possible. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5

Comment: @Pekka Yeah, [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91273/155160) has two bounties on it from you. Feel free to definitively answer here and collect precious reps. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible, at least on Meta. Proof: [this answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91273/155160)

It's unlikely the behaviour will be different on the main site.