# Why not treat initial close-as-duplicate similar to answers from a rep perspective?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Of the vote-to-close reasons, marking as "duplicate" seems unique in that:

- It immediately results in the OP getting his question answered
- It frequently requires knowledge of the subject comparable to what it
  would take to answer the question directly *as well as* requiring
  knowledge of the SO repository or ability/willingness to search
- It involves forgoing reputation which would otherwise likely accrue to
  the person identifying the duplicate

Similarly, adding an additional vote with the same dup target seems akin to "upvoting" an existing answer.

As such, what would be the effects of incentivizing the first mark-as-duplicate voter with something equivalent to an "accept" or "upvote" rep gain *once the question is closed*, even if a smaller amount (e.g. 5 points)?

Comment: Related: [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620)

Comment: @perhapsPekka LOL +2/5/10 to you. You should VTC. :-)