# Username has Two Display Forms

Tags: bug, user-interface, display-names

I believe this is a bug?

Question-in-question: [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5?rq=1)

User-related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/pekka

[image]

Comment: The question hasn't been edited since Pekka changed his username, so the CW box is showing the old username... I'm guessing we just... don't run the query to get the primary contributor unless the post gets changed.