# Is it possible to use SEDE to plot the pageviews for a specific question over time?

Tags: support, data-explorer, views, time

I answered a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/70490/chemical-reaction-in-homemade-deodorant) on Chem.SE earlier today and noticed just now that it'd made it to HNQ.  This got me wondering just how big the HNQ Effect™ is in terms of a jump in pageviews.

I found a [handful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109974/is-it-possible-to-quantify-the-quality-of-questions-over-time) of other [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148445/plot-upvotes-over-time-for-an-answer) using auxiliary data to [estimate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105693/graph-trends-for-activity-within-tags) time trends, but all of them rely on that auxiliary data having an independent `CreationDate` or other interaction timestamp that represents a proxy for that action.

Can I plot the `ViewCount` for a given `@PostID` over time with SEDE? Given that the database appears to be a snapshot in time, and that `ViewCount` seems to be a "thin" quantity without associated time-/datestamp information, I'm not very hopeful... but! This is why we ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't plot viewcount over time from SEDE.

The viewcount is recorded in the posts table for question types (posttypeid = 1)  and that table only holds the last known value.

Significant actions on a post are kept in the posthistory table but a view is not considered to be a significant event and isn't stored there either.

Your only option is to track questions by [your self](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/loutish-rod) that appear in the [hot questions list](https://loutish-rod.glitch.me/) and their viewcount (which is available from the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=292366&filter=!8IgyDPPl9-4O(XEMnvmBQ&site=meta&run=true)) and store that in your own datastore at regular intervals for processing later.