# Unable to custom flag an author-deleted post that I previously flagged as spam/abusive, as I can't retract my pending red flag

Tags: bug, flags, spam, deleted-posts

I just flagged a spam post here as spam. The author later self-deleted the post. Due to my as-of-yet pending spam flag ([which remains on the post after the author deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273402/377214)), I'm unable to cast a moderator flag on the post, as I can't have two pending flags on the same post at the same time.

This may seem like intentional design, as I'm supposed to retract my previous flag before I can cast another one. However, I'm unable to retract my previous flag. Instead of the radio buttons in the flag dialog being disabled and the submit button being replaced with a retract button, the flag dialog renders as if I have no pending flag: the radio buttons (or in this case, singular button, as the only option is custom "in need of moderator intervention") are selectable, and the option to submit the flag is still there. When I attempt to submit, I get an error message saying I already have a pending flag on the post.

Per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294586/377214), if the author of a spam post self-deletes it, I should custom flag it asking that it be changed to a proper spam deletion. I prefer to do exactly that rather than keeping my previous red flag pending, as a moderator may simply see that it's deleted without checking and ensuring that it was a proper red-flag deletion, and I'd prefer to point them to that.

However, if the author deletes a post which *I've already red-flagged*, I'm unable to retract my prior red flag on it.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: _"a moderator may simply see that it's deleted without checking and ensuring that it was a proper red-flag deletion"_ Wouldn't moderators see that the spam flag is not handled and still need to handle it though? Or is my assumption incorrect?

Comment: I agree that one should be able to retract their flag nonetheless though.

Comment: @41686d6564 They may not be aware of the system's behavior that spam flags don't get cleared on author deletions *only*. Also, if [this feature request of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316453/dont-invalidate-spam-or-abuse-flags-upon-review-deletion) gets implemented, it won't be the case.