# Big number of not programming related question on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users

I see some problems on Stack Overflow. There are many new questions which are not related with programming. I spent all my close votes within half an hour ;-/ As the popularity of Stack Overflow grows, more of these questions get posted from newbies.

New users don't know the other Stack Exchange sites, so they ask on Stack Overflow.

Maybe increasing the number of close votes would improve the situation.

Comment: Yep. [Should we encourage more closing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38057/should-we-encourage-more-closing). The thing that makes it *more* frustrating now is that there are proper homes for a larger fraction of these non-questions. ::sigh::

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that more close-votes would do any good, though I don't know any numbers or statistics. There are more then 3.000 users out there which are allowed to issue close calls, and some pretty fast diamond mods which can close as many questions as they'd like to.

If you run out of close-votes, don't worry, there are many other users which will keep voting. Alternatively, you can start to educate the users, commenting on their questions and explaining what they did wrong (many questions are abandoned after migration).

Comment: If you flag for moderator attention, *please* take the time to leave a comment link to the site where you think the question belongs if there's not a migration path set up yet.  This will save us a lot of time getting through the mod queue.  Thanks.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I didn't mean flagging, I meant voting...sorry for the confusion. I'd never suggest to flag for moderator attention 'just' to close a question, because this will sort out itself in time without the need for extra work for you diamond mods.

Comment: Your original sentence was correct though, "...there are many other users which will keep flagging."  :)